# Apache Flume stopped streaming Twitter data after Twitter API SSL/TLS mandatory requirements.

Tags: ssl, twitter, hadoop, flume

I have followed cloudera's tutorial (http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/09/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop/) for an application to ingest twitter data into HDFS using Apache Flume. 
Twitter has restricted its api connection to SSL/TLS only with effect from 15th January 2014. After this change my Flume agent has stopped streaming the twitter data.
Kindly reply if you have already implemented the respective changes to cater for new requirements based on specs in follwoing article.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/security/using-ssl

Thanks,
Hussnain

Comment: Post some code. If you followed some tutorial you should have written some code.

Comment: My flume.conf have following code for source \n TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = <my consumer key>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = <my consumer secret>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken =<my access token> 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = <my access token secret>

Comment: TwitterSource file has following code for access <br/> public void configure(Context context) {
    consumerKey = context.getString(TwitterSourceConstants.CONSUMER_KEY_KEY);
    consumerSecret = context.getString(TwitterSourceConstants.CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY);
    accessToken = context.getString(TwitterSourceConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
    accessTokenSecret = context.getString(TwitterSourceConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY);

    String keywordString = context.getString(TwitterSourceConstants.KEYWORDS_KEY, "");

Comment: issue got resolved after I installed newer version of twitter4j i.e v 3.0.3 that is using HTTPS. For reference see  <br/> http://jira.twitter4j.org/browse/TFJ-632   <br/> and comments on  <br/> http://www.datadansandler.com/2013/03/making-clouderas-twitter-stream-real.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue got resolved after I installed newer version of twitter4j i.e v 3.0.3 that is using HTTPS. For reference see   
 jira.twitter4j.org/browse/TFJ-632   
 and comments on   
http://www.datadansandler.com/2013/03/making-clouderas-twitter-stream-real.html?showComment=1390047763159#c8713000610110252026