# Apache Flume connection to the twitter API 401:Authentication credentials

Tags: hadoop, twitter, cloudera, flume, cloudera-manager

I am trying to use Apache Flume for saving tweets to my HDFS. I am currently using the Cloudera image with Hadoop and Flume. I was following the tutorial from Cloudera's blog, but I am not able to connect to the Twitter API.

I am getting following error:

```
2014-03-14 09:43:14,021 INFO org.apache.flume.node.Application: Waiting for channel: MemChannel to start. Sleeping for 500 ms
2014-03-14 09:43:14,069 INFO org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: MemChannel: Successfully registered new MBean.
2014-03-14 09:43:14,069 INFO org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: CHANNEL, name: MemChannel started
2014-03-14 09:43:14,522 INFO org.apache.flume.node.Application: Starting Sink HDFS
2014-03-14 09:43:14,522 INFO org.apache.flume.node.Application: Starting Source Twitter
2014-03-14 09:43:14,525 INFO org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: HDFS: Successfully registered new MBean.
2014-03-14 09:43:14,525 INFO org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: HDFS started
2014-03-14 09:43:14,595 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Establishing connection.
2014-03-14 09:43:14,680 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2014-03-14 09:43:14,823 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2014-03-14 09:43:14,946 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:41414
2014-03-14 09:43:16,249 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.

HTTP ERROR: 401

Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/filter.json'. Reason:
Unauthorized



2014-03-14 09:43:16,249 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Waiting for 10000 milliseconds
2014-03-14 09:43:26,251 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Establishing
```

I have copied my twitter API credentials to the flume.conf (I have tried in both on disc and web UI). I have also tried to regenerate them again and copy those new ones, but it didn't help me.

My pom.xml contains:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

That means that there shouldn't be the problem that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162617/apache-flume-stopped-streaming-twitter-data-after-twitter-api-ssl-tls-mandatory).

And I have also set the system time by command:

```
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

Does anybody have some idea of what can possibly be wrong?
Thank you very much in advance for any suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to Twitter4J 3.0.6.. I resolved a similar issue by upgrading to 3.0.6

Comment: I have updated for 3.0.6, but unfortunately I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Its because of invalid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and make sure to have the system clock is in sync."